# Force lapply/sapply to index output list with inputs

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply, indices

As in the title, how to force lapply or sapply to use input vector values to index the output.
I have two cases; let me begin with the simpler one. The following code

```
lapply(c('a', 'b'), function(idx){
    rnorm(1)
})
```

gives me the output

```
[[1]]
[1] -1.359386

[[2]]
[1] -0.3428958
```

but I would like to receive:

```
$a
[1] -1.359386

$b
[1] -0.3428958
```

In the final aim, my code looks like follows:

```
m = sapply(unique(isotopes[, 1]), function(el){
    sapply(isotopes[isotopes$element == el, 2], function(mnr){
        isotopes[isotopes$element == el & isotopes$mass_nr == mnr, 3]
    })
})
```

and it gives me outputs like

```
$Pu
[1] 238.0496 239.0522 240.0538 241.0569 242.0587 244.0642
```

while I would like to obtain list of lists, to be able to use `m['Pu'][240]` or `m['Pu']['240']` etc. (for 'Pu' `isotopes[isotopes$element == el, 2]` is a vector of 238 239 240 241 242 244)

PS. Of course, I can use

```
m = function(el, mnr){ isotopes[isotopes$element == el & isotopes$mass_nr == mnr, 3] }
```

but I'm interested if the above problem possesses a neat solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
lapply(c(a = "a", b = "b"), function(idx) {
    rnorm(1)
})
```

which should give the desired output

```
$a
[1] 1.556433

$b
[1] -0.2282002
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split the data set twice, use `split` twice, it returns a named list.

In the code below I have used a column name `third_col`, not the column number.

```r
set.seed(2023)
n <- 20L
isotopes <- data.frame(
  element = sample(letters[1:2], n, TRUE),
  mass_nr = sample(3, n, TRUE),
  third_col = rnorm(n)
)


sp <- split(isotopes, isotopes$element) 
lapply(sp, \(x) split(x$third_col, x$mass_nr))
#> $a
#> $a$`1`
#> [1]  0.8602705 -0.1299832  0.1092238  0.1615685 -1.5131984  1.1431521
#> 
#> $a$`2`
#> [1] -0.4709085 -0.4389865 -1.1927195 -1.1326977
#> 
#> $a$`3`
#> [1]  0.8468178 -1.3264019  0.9712922
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$`1`
#> [1] 1.9957190 0.1108168
#> 
#> $b$`2`
#> [1]  0.7522100  0.9254184 -0.2917223
#> 
#> $b$`3`
#> [1] -0.2294296 -0.7137467
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or with a pipe from the first `split` to a `lapply/split`. Then extract a couple of named list members.

```r
m <- split(isotopes, isotopes$element) |> lapply(\(x) split(x$third_col, x$mass_nr))

m$a[['2']]
#> [1] -0.4709085 -0.4389865 -1.1927195 -1.1326977

m$b$`3`
#> [1] -0.2294296 -0.7137467
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another way - use `sapply()` with the option `simplify = FALSE` to get a list as output:

```
sapply(c('a', 'b'), \(idx) rnorm(1), simplify = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
$a
[1] 0.4824588

$b
[1] 0.7582138
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it only works if the vector we iterate consists of strings; in doesn't work in the case of numerical vector (in my final aim) :(